# Data driven tests. reading parameters from a .json or .yaml file using Selenium Python

Tags: python, json, selenium, pyyaml

I create a framework using Selenium and Python. 
My data driven framework consists of 2 files so far: 
    The 1st file- `Setup.py` contains class `Actions()` 
    that consist of all possible functions that I will use
    in my framework, such as:

```
def __init__(): 
def setup():
def tearDown():
def click():
def sendKeys():
```

My `click` and `sendKeys` functions have a minimum of 2 parameters. 
    They take the first parameter such us `:id_for_element`, 
    `xp_for_element`, or `css_for_element`, slicing words until
    they get the 1st two characters and find element by either
    id, xp or any other way. Then they use the 2nd parameter to 
    specify  an element's value, and 3rd parameter to specify 
    a value for `send_keys()` function. All of these functions 
    are now working, but so far value hardcoded in my test file.

`setup.py file`:

```
from   selenium import webdriver
from   selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from   selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from   selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from   selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from   selenium.common.exceptions import NoAlertPresentException

class Actions(object):

    def __init__(self,driver=None):
        if driver != None:
            self.driver = driver

    def setUp(self, browserName):
        if browserName == 'Chrome':
            self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
            self.driver.delete_all_cookies()
            self.driver.maximize_window()
        elif browserName == 'Safari':
            self.driver = webdriver.Safari()
            self.driver.delete_all_cookies()
            self.driver.maximize_window()
        elif browserName == 'Firefox':
            self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
            self.driver.delete_all_cookies()
            self.driver.maximize_window()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)

    def tearDown(self, browserName):
        self.driver.quit()

    def webPage(self):
        self.driver.get('https://www.yahoo.com')

    def click(self, elemLocator, elemValue):
        elp = elemLocator
        flp = slice(0,2)
        if elp[flp] == 'id':#return by ID
            try:
                self.driver.find_element_by_id(elemValue).click()
            except:
                pass
        elif elp[flp] == 'xp':#return by XPATH
            try:
                self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(elemValue).click()
            except:
                pass


    def sendKeys(self, elemLocator, elemValue, messageValue):
        elp = elemLocator
        flp = slice(0,2)
        if elp[flp] == 'id':#return by ID
            try:
                self.driver.find_element_by_id(elemValue).click()
                self.driver.find_element_by_id(elemValue).clear()
                self.driver.find_element_by_id(elemValue).send_keys(messageValue)
            except:
                pass

        elif elp[flp] == 'xp':#return by XPATH
            try:
                self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(elemValue).click()
                self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(elemValue).clear()
                self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(elemValue).send_keys(messageValue)
            except:
                pass

#test.py file

    from Setup import Actions

class test_case_1: #find element by id

    action = Actions(object)
    action.setUp('Chrome')
    action.webPage()
    action.click('id_of_yahoo_logo', 'uh-logo')
    action.tearDown('Chrome')


class test_case_2: #find element by xpath

    action = Actions(object)
    action.setUp('Chrome')
    action.webPage()
    action.click('xp_of signIn_button', '//*[@id="uh-signin"]')
    action.tearDown('Chrome')

class test_case_3: #login to email

    action = Actions(object)
    action.setUp('Chrome')
    action.webPage()
    action.click('xp_of signIn_button', '//*[@id="uh-signin"]')
    action.sendKeys('id_username_login_inp_field','login-username','deniska')
    action.click('id_of submit_button', 'login-signin')
    action.tearDown('Chrome')
```

Instead I am trying to pass value for parameters from another 
    file as described by the best practices for data driven testing 
    framework. My next step is to create a `data.json` file that 
    I will use to map out all elements of the DOM in the following 
    format: "id_login_button":"some id value", "xp_input_field":"some 
    xp value" etc. Can someone, please, help me figure out 
    how to implement this technique?

Comment: I would go with a YAML file for the data-driven part. The multi-document features combined with tags and root-level literal style scalars make it IMO superior to JSON to use, especially if you are in parallel developing/extending the framework and writing tests. One of the "frameworks" I am using is public [here](https://bitbucket.org/ruamel/yaml/src/default/_test/test_z_data.py) with data it works on [here](https://bitbucket.org/ruamel/yaml.data/src/default/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the simple approach if you want to use the json as your uiRepo.

**sample.json:**

```
{
    "id_of_yahoo_logo":"uh-logo",
    "xp_of_signIn_button":"//*[@id='uh-signin']",
    "id_username_login_inp_field":"New York",
    "id_of_submit_button":"login-signin"
}
```

**test.py**

```
# you have to just specify the name as shown below
action.click('xp_of_signIn_button)
```

**Reading value in Actions.py:**

```
import json

#parse json
with open('sample.json') as f:
    uiRepo = json.load(f)

# update the generic methods to get the property form json
print(uiRepo['id_of_yahoo_logo'])
```

**Edit 1:setup.py** Un-Tested updates

```
from   selenium import webdriver
from   selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from   selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from   selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from   selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from   selenium.common.exceptions import NoAlertPresentException
import json

class Actions(object):
    # initialize uiRepo
    uiRepo = None
    def __init__(self,driver=None):
        if driver != None:
            self.driver = driver
            # load the uiRepo from json when you init the driver
            with open('sample.json') as repo:
                uiRepo = json.load(repo)

    def setUp(self, browserName):
        browserName = browserName.lower()
        if browserName == 'chrome':
            self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        elif browserName == 'safari':
            self.driver = webdriver.Safari()
        elif browserName == 'firefox':
            self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.delete_all_cookies() #< === moved this line
        self.driver.maximize_window() #< === moved this line
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)

    def tearDown(self): #< === Removed browser here as you don't need browser name while closing it.
        self.driver.quit()

    def webPage(self,url): #< === Added url as param, rather hard code
        self.driver.get(url)

    # new method to get the element based on the jsonKey
    def getElement(self, jsonKey):
        locatorStrategy = jsonKey[:2]  # <=== getting first 2 chars to figure out if it's id/xp
        locator = uiRepo[jsonKey]  # < == getting value from json
        ele = None
        try:
            if locatorStrategy == 'id':  # return by ID
                ele =  self.driver.find_element_by_id(locator).click()  # <=== using the locator got from json
            elif locatorStrategy == 'xp':  # return by XPATH
                ele =  self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(locator).click()
        except:
            pass
        # if you want you can add additional logic something like highlighting the element
        return ele

    def click(self, jsonKey): # < ==== updated method to accept only jsonElementName (Removed the element value param)
        ele = self.findElement(jsonKey)
        ele.click()
```

Comment: I see some enhancement/optimization points in your Actions class. Will Add that under Edit 1.

Comment: Dear supputuri! Thank for very much for your help!                                               def getValue(key):
    value = ''
    with open('data.json') as f:
        uiRepo = json.load(f)
        value = (uiRepo[key])
    return value

Comment: and modified my click():                                                                                                                                                                                              def click(self, elemLocator):
        elemValue = getValue(elemLocator)
        elp = elemLocator
        flp = slice(0,2)
        if elp[flp] == 'id':#return by ID

Comment: Have you checked the updated `setup.py` in my answer.